# Matplotlib savefig() slow ...just the way things are or ideas to speed up?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I've got some code where I'm using MPL (not pyplot) via `imshow()` to show some arrays and then am using `savefig()` to save them as PNG files.

The arrays are approx 3,000 x 4,000 in size.

My problem is that saving is taking a long time - **on the order of 4 seconds or so per image.**

#### Minor Details

- The arrays are floats
- I'm using cmap of gray
- I'm making sure the figure resolution is the same as the images, and the axes fills the entire figure (so fig size * dpi matches exactly the shape of the arrays)
- I'm using `imshow()` with interpolation of `none`.
- Running on macbook pro - but running on anything else is about the same (assuming SSD)

---

The slowness seems to be due to **CPU bottleneck**.  Using `time` wrapped around my code shows real and user time to be about the same, so it doesn't seem to be a IO bottleneck.

However, (very curiously!), if I run the code via Multiprocessing in multiple processes, it doesn't seem to help much with overall real time (even with 4 cores).

### Questions

- Is saving to PNG taking around 4 seconds 'normal'?
- Any tips or ideas on how to speed things up?

Answer (score 1):

Never tried it but I think you could try to run the code via Multiprocessing using the GPU (which may be more suited for the process) if you have Nvidia graphic card.
https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/
Other than that I don't think you can speed up the process more.

Answer (score 0):

From the details of what you are doing it sounds like you just want to save the array as a (false) color image.  You are very carefully setting up Matplotlib to do that for you, but we do not have the logic to notice we can take any short-cuts so are still going through all of the resampling logic.

You can generate an equivalent output more simply via:

```py
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.cm as mcm
import numpy as np
import PIL
import time


# "data"
my_data = np.random.randn(3000, 4000) * 50

start_time = time.monotonic()
# to scale the data to [0, 1]
my_norm = mcolors.Normalize(-50, 50)
# to map the scaled data to gray scale RGB
my_cmap = mcm.get_cmap('gray')
setup_time = time.monotonic()
# apply the above transforms
color_mapped = my_cmap(my_norm(my_data), bytes=True)
mapping_time = time.monotonic()
# use pillow to save the png
PIL.Image.fromarray(color_mapped).save('/tmp/so.png', compress_level=1)
end_time = time.monotonic()


print(f"saving took {end_time - start_time}")
print(f"  setup took {setup_time - start_time}")
print(f"  mapping took {mapping_time - setup_time}")
print(f"  saving took {end_time - mapping_time}")
```

but a majority of the time is still spent in `.save(...)`.  By playing with `compress_level` you can make that line more/less expensive which suggests that cost is inside of libpng while compressing the data (see https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#png).

Comment: Thanks!  I'd looked into PIL previously, but I also at times need to create some reasonably complex overlays etc that just aren't supported by PIL unfortunately, so I had to stick with MPL.

Comment: In my playing around with this, PIL was taking ~4 sec to save and as of 3.3 we use PIL (rather than a home-grown wrapping of libpng) to save png so you may be at a performance edge.

Comment: Interesting!  So it's not a magic silver bullet!  ...thanks for checking and posting!